# "This isn't the place for you" meaning?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

Would you say that this line is an indirect way of telling someone they shouldn't come/be somewhere? Or if not indirect, maybe some other adjective?

Comment: Yes, in most cases the statement would be interpreted either as implying that that individual being addressed is at some risk from being present, due to some physical or moral hazard (eg, a child in a porn store), or as implying that the individual is sticking his nose where it doesn't belong.

Comment: I see. I guess just to give you the whole picture, the person who said this line said it because they didn't like how someone else chose to spend their time there, namely on the subjects they chose to talk about. It wasn't inappropriate, dangerous, or even disallowed, the person just thinks that they're wasting their time doing so and apparently thinks they'd be better off elsewhere. I don't know if that changes anything for you, but I like what you've said so far.

Comment: That would fit somewhere in between the other two.  The motivation of the speaking party is unclear -- he may see a "risk" to the party being addressed in terms of time/effort/skills wasted, or he may be being somewhat judgmental and believe that the situation is somehow morally inappropriate.

Comment: I would go with him thinking it's morally inappropriate, based on his overall attitude.

Comment: This sentence is not indirect at all.